# What type of data does the $(this) return in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am confused about what type of data `$(this)` returns in jQuery.

Comment: `this` is the element combined with `$()` makes it a jquery object

Answer (score 1):

It will be an object (If you are searching for the type you can simply check for it in the chrome console typeof $(this))

Comment: This works fine for me